# How to order enum alphabetically rather than on int?

Tags: c#, linq, enums

Let's say I want my user to be able to sort a table based on an enum value

My enum would look like this:

```
public enum Letter
{
    C= 0,
    A,
    B,
    E,
    D,            
}
```

A query could look like this:

```
var letters = from l in context.Example
                  orderby l.Letter
                  select l;
```

The ascending/descending order will be based on the enum int value rather than alphabetical order. Is there an easy way to programatically order it alphabetically? Obviously I could sort it myself in my Enum Class but this could become mundane work on larger enums.

How I want it to be sorted:

```
//A       ACTUAL  //C
//B       ACTUAL  //A
//C       ACTUAL  //B
//D       ACTUAL  //E
//E       ACTUAL  //D
```

Comment: What's `context.Example`? Is it `IQueryable<T>`? Are you using EntityFramework?

Comment: Yes it was just a hypothetical example

Comment: Did any of the provided solutions worked?

Answer (score 4):

You could use this snippet:

```
Letter[] allletters =  Enum.GetValues(typeof(Letter)).Cast<Letter>().ToArray();
var sortedLetters = allletters.OrderBy(l => l.ToString());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [**`Enum.GetName`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname(v=vs.110).aspx) method (or `ToString()` if we can rely that this will return the name):

```
var letters = from l in context.Example
              orderby Enum.GetName(l.Letter.GetType(),l.Letter)
              select l;
```

This could also work if the `l.Letter` can return different enums. It will fail however if it returns a non-enum. This can be (un)wanted behavior. In case you use `ToString()` you thus compare the objects based on their name. But any object (normally) supports a `ToString()` method.

For example:

```
csharp> enum Foo {
      > A,
      > B,
      > C
      > }
csharp> enum Bar {
      > AB,
      > ZZ,
      > X
      > }
csharp> var l = new object[] {Foo.C,Foo.B,Bar.ZZ,Bar.AB,Bar.X,Foo.A};
csharp> from li in l orderby Enum.GetName(li.GetType(),li) select li;  
{ A, AB, B, C, X, ZZ }
```

That being said, it usually makes not much sense to mix enums together.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Letter[] letters = (Letter[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Letter));
IEnumerable<Letter> sorted = values.OrderBy(v => v.ToString());
```